# How can I back up Snapper snapshots using BTRFS send/recieve?

Tags: btrfs, snapper

Experimenting on a VM with BTRFS & Snapper.  I have been able to take snapshots, undochanges, delete snapshots, etc using Snapper.

It is not clear to me, how to back up the resulting snapshots to another system and then use the back-up to restore the source system.

- I have successfully used Send/Receive to send my snapshot from SOURCE-SYSTEM to a different sub-volume (TARGET-SYSTEM).
- I used snapper to delete the snapshot from SOURCE-SYSTEM.
- Used Send/Receive to restore the deleted snapshots on the SOURCE-SYSTEM
- But Snapper [does not recognize the snapshot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/750666/how-can-i-get-snapper-to-recognize-a-snapshot).

So the question is how should I back up and restore the snapshots created by snapper?

Comment: Since `btrfs send|receive` are not `snapper` commands, `snapper` won't know about the backups they create. My guess is that you'd need to restore the target-system snapshot to your source-system, then restore it manually. Maybe this link will help: https://fedoramagazine.org/working-with-btrfs-snapshots/